# Establishing secure connection delays homepage load (adsense)

Tags: javascript, html, https, youtube-api, adsense

This only happens when i activate my two desktop adsense units in the index.html (which is the only page cause it's a single page website).

Randomly it gets stuck on **Establishing secure connection...** (at the bottom left corner of the window) for 6-15 seconds then it loads the rest of the page.

I'm using google analytics async, adsense async, and youtube-api (i don't load a video on page load tho).

Also i exclusively use https links all around my website, and the domain obviously is loaded on https.

I've tried to add in the `<head>` this line but doesn't change:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

When this happens, in the console once it completed loading it throws me either this error:

> GET
>   https://image6.pubmatic.com/AdServer/UCookieSetPug?oid=1&rd=https%3A%2F%2Fcm.g.doubleclick.net
>   [..] net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

or something like:

> :ERR_TIMED_OUT                       UCookieSetPug?:1

Comment: Have you checked this Google forum about [Chrome keep saying Establishing Secure Connection](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/SYBB6iGbnfQ)?

Comment: Last comment says "This is still happening on brand new windows 10 installation with new Chrome installed" i guess hasn't be solved there either? also when you search about the issue all speak from their browser perspective, i'd want to be sure this isn't happening to users visiting my site because of some bug happening from my side

Answer (score -1):

In,

> Services > Cryptographic Services > Log On >

Make sure that `Log on as: Local system account` is ticked and **not** `This account`.